# combine two text separated by one series in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to combine odd columns' text and even columns' text.

**sample series**

```
   column
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

and I want this output

```
   column
0   ab
1   cd
```

I tried

```
new_df['new'] = df['column'][::2].map(str) + df['column'][1::2]
```

but it returns

```
   new
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your desired output you've combined even indexes with odd. Is that what you require?

Comment: yes, thats what i want. I have 'league of legends' matches data, and im trying to get bottom combo from players information of matches.

Comment: If there are more than 4 rows, how should output look like? Will it have only 2 rows?

Comment: no, it will have n/2 rows. e.g)12, 34,56, ...

Comment: So according to your output, you need combination of indexes such as [01, 23, 45, 67, 89, ...] for given series. Is that right?

Comment: @AmeyDahale Yes, thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by `reshape`ing the underlying `numpy` array, construct a new df from this and then `apply` a str `join`:

```
In[14]:
pd.DataFrame(df['column'].values.reshape((2,-1))).apply(''.join, axis=1)

Out[14]: 
0    ab
1    cd
dtype: object
```

Slightly more obscure is after reshaping is to `sum` row-wise which will concatenate the strings:

```
In[15]:
pd.DataFrame(df['column'].values.reshape((2,-1))).sum(axis=1)

Out[15]: 
0    ab
1    cd
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you concatenate them on indices, which do not match.
You either need to reset indices, or use underlying numpy arrays.

```
>>> df['column'][::2].values + df['column'][1::2].values

array(['ab', 'cd'], dtype=object)

>>> df['column'][::2].reset_index(drop=True) + df['column'][1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
0    ab
1    cd
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using values of `column` as an array and `concat` on even and odd indices as:

```
a = df.column.values
pd.DataFrame(a[::2]+a[1::2],columns=['column'])

    column
0   ab
1   cd
```